# Make - Undefined Reference (C++)

Tags: c++, header, makefile, include

I've looked through questions others have asked but none of the solutions seem to work. I don't understand enough about makefile compiling. But here is my makefile:

```
program.out:    bzstrlib.o DataStructures.o Classes.o main.o
            g++ -o program.out bzstrlib.o DataStructures.o Classes.o main.o

bzstrlib.o:     bzstrlib.cpp bzstrlib.h
            g++ -c bzstrlib.cpp

DataStructures.o:   DataStructures.cpp DataStructures.h
            g++ -c DataStructures.cpp

Classes.o:      Classes.cpp Classes.h
            g++ -c Classes.cpp

main.o:         main.cpp bzstrlib.cpp bzstrlib.h DataStructures.cpp DataStructures.h Classes.cpp Classes.h
            g++ -c main.cpp

clean:
            rm *.o program.out
```

I must have it set up incorrectly, because I keep getting the error message `Classes.o: In function 'Player::dealCard(Card const&)':
Classes.cpp:(.text+0x735): undefined reference to 'List<Card>::gotoEnd()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status.`

`Player` is defined in `Classes` and `List<>::gotoEnd()` is defined in `DataStructures`.

Adding to my confusion, on the line just after the call to `gotoEnd()` is a call to another function defined in the same header. If I comment out the `gotoEnd()` call, then I get no compiler errors, despite the other function's presence.

I have 7 files:

Main.cpp: `#include`s "Classes.h" and "DataStructures.cpp"

bzstrlib.h: does not include any headers

DataStructures.h: does not include any headers

Classes.h: `#include`s "DataStructures.h"

bzstrlib.cpp: `#include`s "bzstrlib.h"

DataStructures.cpp: `#include`s "DataStructures.h"

Classes.cpp: `#include`s "bzstrlib.h", "Classes.h", and "DataStructures.h"

Comment: Why aren't you using make's implict rules?

Comment: Explain to me which specific rules you're referring to. I've never understood how the makefile works. I'd like to know exactly what I'm doing wrong and where; I've read countless other questions here and can't make sense of the answers because they're not specific to my scenario.

Comment: @user1362548 Let a decent IDE (e.g. Eclipse CDT) generate some for you and study these to get a 1st grip!

Comment: `Classes.o` should have `DataStructures.h` as a prerequisite, but that wouldn't cause this error. Could you show us `DataStructures.cpp`?

Answer (score 0):

If the actual implementation for `List<>::gotoEnd` is in `DataStructures.cpp`, then the issue you're likely running into is the fact that the compiler hasn't instantiated `List<Card>::gotoEnd()`.   You'll have to ask it to do so *explicitly*.

You can force the compiler to emit an implementation for `List<Card>` by adding the following line to `DataStructures.cpp`:

```
template class List<Card>;
```

This is called *explicit instantiation*, and is required for some compilers when part or all of the implementation of a templated class is in a different `.cpp` file than the header.  More here:  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template  (Scroll down to Explicit Instantiation).

Comment: I get error: `expected unqualified-id before ';' token` when I add that line.

Comment: Please see my edit; I forgot the word `class` after `template`.